# How to separate $x^2X''v+xX'v+Xv_{yy}+x^2Xv_{zz} = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following partial differential equation:

$$x^2X''v+xX'v+Xv_{yy}+x^2Xv_{zz} = 0,$$

where $X = X(x)$ and $v = v(y,z)$. How to separate it?

Thank you for any help!

From the book:

[image]

Answer from the book:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am pretty rusty on PDE, but I'll give it a shot.
Using $u(x,y,z) = X(x) v(y,z)$, then the equation in question becomes 
$$
\frac{X''}{X} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{X'}{X} + \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{v_{yy}}{v} + \frac{v_{zz}}{v} = 0 .
$$
This gives the equation
$$
\frac{X''}{X} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{X'}{X} = - \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{v_{yy}}{v} + \frac{v_{zz}}{v} \right) 
$$
from which I believe we can conclude that 
$$
\frac{X''}{X} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{X'}{X} = \frac{A}{x^2} + B, \, \frac{v_{yy}}{v} = -A, \, \frac{v_{zz}}{v} = -B.
$$

Comment: One question though...Why could you do equate $\frac{v_{yy}}{v}=-A$ etc. this got me confused?...Why is it a constant...

Comment: Well, the left hand side cannot contain any terms involving $y,z$, and similarly, the term $\frac{v_{zz}}{v}$ cannot have any $x$, so that it must be constant (otherwise you would have that the lefthand side contains $y$ or $z$ terms. Similarly, $\frac{v_{yy}}{v}$ cannot have any $y$ or $z$ terms as that would imply that the lefthand side contains such terms, hence it must be a constant as well. From there, I chose the names of the constants so as to be consistent.